# Show div when on scroll and class called

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a one page app that has 2 sidenavs (nav1 and nav2) and 2 different contents of div. Now I want to do is when I scroll down and get to the point where `class="content2"` is there, `id="nav2"` will show. Then if I scroll up where `class="content1"` is there then the `id="nav1"` will show. As default nav1 shall be shown.

here's some pictures to understand the problem a little

Here's a picture where I am in the content1.
[image]

And here in content2
[image]

and here's a sample [html fiddle](https://fiddle.jshell.net/kcNeko/rjjrmhvt/).

Comment: where is your try code ?

Comment: @kcNeko Have a look my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `$(document).scroll(function()` to detect a change in scroll position of the document.  `scrollTop()` method will give the current top position of the document and `position()` is the method which returns an object containing position values and `top` is what we want in our case. We just want to compare current document top position and div top position.

`if($(this).scrollTop()>=$('.content2').position().top){` which means the current document position is with in the top position of the div with class name `.content2`. now we can show `nav2` and hide `nav1`. Otherwise show `nav1` and hide `nav2`

```
  $(document).scroll(function() {
    if($(this).scrollTop()>=$('.content2').position().top){
      $("#nav2").show();
      $("#nav1").hide();
    }
    else {
      $("#nav1").show();
      $("#nav2").hide();
    }
  })
```

Fiddle: https://fiddle.jshell.net/tintucraju/rjjrmhvt/5/

Please note : `position().top` is calculated from the top to the parent if parent is relatively positioned. so there will be slight change in the top value. you can adjust by adding offset to `$(this).scrollTop()` and adjust to your desired position.

Updated Fiddle : https://fiddle.jshell.net/tintucraju/rjjrmhvt/6/

Answer (score 1):

I took height of both content area and  used 1/3 of window height as offset. You can modify as you want.

```js
      var content1 = $( ".content1" ).position();
          content2 = $( ".content2" ).position();
          offset = $( window ).height()/3;

      $(document).scroll(function() {
        var y = $(this).scrollTop();

        if (y >= content2.top - offset){
          $( "#nav2" ).show();
          $( "#nav1" ).hide();
        }else{
          $( "#nav2" ).hide();
          $( "#nav1" ).show();
        }
      });
```

```css
      .container{
        max-width: 1000px;
        margin: 0 auto 40px auto;
min-height: 800px;
        overflow: hidden;
        clear: both;
      }
      #nav1, #nav2{
        width: 25%px;
        float: left;
        min-height: 200px;
        border: 2px solid #8a6343;
        position: fixed;
        min-width: 100px;
      }
      #nav2{
        top: 0;
        display: none;
      }
      .content1, .content2{
      min-width: 200px;
        width: 60%;
        float: right;
        min-height: 230px;
        border: 2px solid #440044;
      }
      .content2{
        margin-bottom: 200px;
      }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
      <div id="nav1">nav one</div>
      <div class="content1">Content area 1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
      <div id="nav2"> nav two</div>
      <div class="content2"> content area 2</div>
    </div>
```